# How do I create my own resource names?

Tags: android

Can I use my own resource names in `themes.xml`? For example:

```
<item name="headerBackground">@drawable/header</item>
```

In this example, `headerBackground` is not a valid resource (`No resource found that matches the given name...`, says Eclipse).

Where should I create/declare these resources? Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use your own names, otherwise you'd be stuck with the Android default drawables.. :)

You declare drawable names by placing a file with that name in your `res/drawable` directory.

---

**Updated, actual answer:**

You need to declare a styleable attribute, in `res/values/attrs.xml` (the actual filename doesn't matter, but this seems to be the convention):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="headerBackground" format="reference" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then you can assign it a value in your theme, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="headerBackground">@drawable/header</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Of course whatever `View` you're implementing to use this newly-defined attribute has to be able to load that `Drawable` and apply it.  The [Gallery example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.html) on the Android Developers' site is useful there.

Comment: Oh. Maybe the question was not clear. The problem here is that "headerBackground" is not a valid resource type. My question is where do I declare my own resource types - the names of the resources, and not the resource values.